# How to find out diameter of some crater on moon using meteorite size and velocity?

Tags: projectile, space, moon, meteorites

I am looking for a formula to find out the **diameter** of a crater using **meteorite size and velocity**.

Comment: Assume you mean for an object such as the Moon, where you can ignore the effects of friction. Unsurprisingly, NASA has a lot of material on this. A limited search suggests "The factors affecting the appearance of impact craters and ejecta are the size and velocity of the impactor, and the *geology of the target surface*.".  So apparently depends on the target as well. Think people tend to do experiments. You might be able to make some crude estimates using conservation of energy.

Comment: A search on the internet gave the following reference that I think you may find useful: http://ntrs.nasa.gov/search.jsp?R=19890012010